# send me to detail view after taking picture with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm stuck on the following issue: When I'm taking a picture with UIImagePickerController i want to send the user to another view where the selected image is visible and he/she can fill some more information. But the detailview doesn't show up, instead of that when I take the picture the app hangs, even though the picture is saved on my phone. What can I do?

My code:

```
@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

@end


#import "PhotoViewController.h"
#import "PostViewController.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>

@implementation PhotoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.image == nil) {
        self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        self.imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        } else {
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        }

        self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];

        [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        // A photo was taken/selected!
        self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        if (self.imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            // Save the image!
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also posted my Storyboard to make things clear.
[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot is too small to be legible. Post a link to a file on another site.

In any case, it looks to me like the problem is that you're not dismissing the image picker.

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    //--------------------------------------------------
    //This is the line you're missing
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    //--------------------------------------------------
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        // A photo was taken/selected!
        self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        if (self.imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            // Save the image!
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's only marginally better. Did you see my answer? I told you the likely problem and the solution to that problem.

Comment: that was indeed the problem , kinda stupid of me.. i Will accept your answer. Thank u for the help :)